# how to start coap server in camel-coap-starter springboot

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, coap

I am trying to use some CoAP server implementation for my sprint server.

Now I am trying to write spring controller for my server, I came across https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.camel/camel-coap-starter but I could't see any server example ..

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/devices/")
public class CoapController {


    @PostMapping(value="/temp")
public ResponseEntity<String>  CreateDeviceTemp(){

}
```

But I could not get how to integrate the camel-coap-starter code in my resource and how to start the coap server ?

Comment: As many open source project camel offers some kind of voluntary support, see https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/support.html. Maybe you get answers there. If you want to use a java coap implementation directly (without spring), you may consider to use eclipse/californium, see https://github.com/eclipse/californium . That is also the library, camel is using.